# Is $f(x-at)$ a solution to the heat equation?? ($u_t=u_{xx}$)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

> Show that the heat equation $u_t = u_{xx}$ has solutions of the form $u(x, t) = f (x − at)$ where $a$ is a constant. Show that $a$ can have any value, real or complex, and describe the behavior of the solutions in both cases.

I'm a little unsure of what this question is looking for? Because when I plug f into the heat equation I'm left with $-af_t=f_{xx}$

Any guidance would be appreciated

Comment: $f$ is a one variable function, it does not have $t$ or $x$ partials per se

Comment: gotcha. So how does this change the problem?

Comment: Well once you fix this, you will note that $f$ doesn't solve a PDE but something simpler.

Comment: @meff11, recall the the chain rule for derivatives.

Comment: Call $g(x,t)=x-at$. Now the chain rule can be used to compute the $x$ and $t$ derivatives of $f(g(x,t))$.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

To elaborate on the discussion in the messages, let $u(x,t) = f(x-at)$ for some twice differentiable function $f$ and a constant $a \in \mathbb{C}$. Note that
$$
u_t = \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}
    = \frac{\partial f(x-at)}{\partial t}
    = f'(x-at) \frac{\partial [x-at]}{\partial t}
    = -a f'(x-at).
$$
Can you use a similar technique (Chain Rule, really) to compute $u_x, u_{xx}$ and verify that this form of $u$ indeed satisfies the desired equation?

Comment: So $u_t = -af'$ and $u_x = f'$ and $u_{xx}=f'$ so my equation becomes $-af'=f''$ which would just be an ODE, right?

Comment: yes you are correct :)

Comment: one last question: when I'm solving this ODE and and do integration, what is the integration in respect to? (x-at)?

Comment: @meff11 yes, exactly. You can call it $y$ for convenience and do everything in one variable $y$...